# Upserting Lead with REST API not working

Tags: rest-api, leads

I am trying to make a PATCH call to upsert a Lead (no other objects like Contact or Account are involved). I am using the REST API. I have created a custom field called `MyUniqueField` and set it to be unique and used as an external id. This call keeps failing and returns

```
{
    "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND",
    "message": "The requested resource does not exist"
}
```

I have verified that `MyUniqueField` is returned in the `{{base_url}}/services/data/v53.0/sobjects/Lead/describe` object and it is visible on the admin panel.

I've tried making the PATCH call with different variations of `MyUniqueField` like
`/sobjects/Lead/MyUniqueField__c/123` or `/sobjects/Lead/MyUniqueField/123` but the result is the same.

This is the PATCH call I am making as a curl:

```
curl --location --request PATCH 'http://xxx.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v53.0/sobjects/Lead/MyUniqueField__c/123' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer access_token_here' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "Name": "Test",
    "Email": "test@test.com",
    "Phone": "222-222-2222"
}'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would be `.../MyUNiqueField__c/,,,`  Does the running user for the REST query have FLS on this field? Did you match the field API name perfectly (case insensitive)?

Comment: @cropredy Yes, the user for the REST query has full admin rights and FLS would allow him to access the field. Yes, the field API name is exact.

Comment: sorry - I meant case sensitive; the whole URL is case sensitive starting with the first `/` - but you probably have checked that already